# Cannot add COM DLL as reference to VS 2012 Project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll

I am trying to add A COM DLL built using Visual Studio .NET 2003 ATL COM Project, When I hit Browse and choose the DLL I get the following error

```
A reference to 'MyCOM.dll' could not be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it is a valid assembly or COM component.
```

But when I register it using `RegSvr32.exe` and browse it using COM pane in References window and add it, it works fine.

How can I add just the dll without having to register it ?

Answer (score 1):

That's not so easily possible, because COM always uses the registry to find the DLL. In the code, you're only referencing the library using its GUID and not its location in the file system. Fortunately, that is not exactly true (any more). There are two possibilities to circumvent this:

- Use Reg-Free COM, this requires that you add a manifest to the executable. This contains the registration information instead of the registry. Google for Registration-Free COM and Manifests.
- Often, it is also possible to just link the dll the ordinary way (using the lib file) and create the "COM"-Object using a simple new-call. This requires that you have the full header files, though. And it's not really using COM any more.